# SQL get characters in between string and special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I am trying to convert the format of work weeks. The current format looks like this:

```
workweek
------------
2020ww20.5
2020ww18.3
2019ww05.2
```

I want to convert format to:

```
workweek
------------
202020
202018
202005
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
SUBSTRING(workweek,
    CHARINDEX('ww',workweek)+2,
    CHARINDEX('.',workweek)- CHARINDEX('ww',workweek)-1)

workweek outcome: 202020.
```

I've also tried

```
SUBSTRING(workweek,
    PATINDEX('%ww%', workweek)+1,
    PATINDEX('%.%', workweek) - PATINDEX('%ww%', workweek))

workweek outcome: 2020w20
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `201905` instead of `202005` on the third row?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings always follow this fixed format, then `substring()` is just enough:

```
concat(
    substring(workweek, 1, 4),
    substring(workweek, 7, 2)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65027e76f8d0760eccc5ed556b8b9492)**:

```
select workweek, concat(substring(workweek, 1, 4), substring(workweek, 7, 2)) result
from (values ('2020ww20.5'), ('2020ww18.3'), ('2019ww05.2')) as t(workweek);
```

```
workweek   | result
:--------- | :-----
2020ww20.5 | 202020
2020ww18.3 | 202018
2019ww05.2 | 201905
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `replace` "ww" and get everything `left` to the 6th character

```
  left(replace(workweek,'ww',''),6)
```